# String conversion to valid date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, type-conversion

I need to convert a string to a valid date format

I have tried using cast and convert functions to no avail.

```
Convert( mystring, mm/dd/yy)
```

I have got a string like: Tuesday, July 09, 2019 12:00 AM  to get the output mm/dd/yy . I am not able to get this work.

Tuesday, July 09, 2019 12:00 AM---> mm/dd/yy

Comment: Storing dates as a `varchar` in your database is a bad idea in the first place. `'12/01/2010'` is not **after** `'07/01/2019'`. Use the appropriate datatype in your database (`date` seems like the right one here), and have your application do the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important hint was provided by Larnu as a comment: Do not store date as string, rather use the native date formats and think about the string format in output scenarios only.

So hopefully you are trying to fix this technical issue and therefore you need this conversion in order to store the values in neatly typed columns ;-)

The suggestion by gotqn is the best, as you obviously need to use a specific language/culture and `TRY_PARSE` is the only approach which allows to specify this parameter. `TRY_PARSE` will need at least v2012 and - this might be a draw back, it is really slow.

So, if this is a *one-way-ticket* (just one conversion in order to store your values correctly) and you have a very large count of rows, you might go this route:

```
DECLARE @yourstring VARCHAR(100)='Tuesday, July 09, 2019 12:00 AM';

SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@yourstring,CHARINDEX(',',@yourstring)+1,100) AS datetime);
```

The simple idea is: Cut away the leading Weekday's name. The rest is working implitly.

Comment: This is exactly what i was about to post, apart from using `STUFF` instead of `SUBSTRING`. :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('Tuesday, July 09, 2019 12:00 AM' AS DATETIME USING 'en-US')
```

to convert to valid date.

Then:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TRY_PARSE('Tuesday, July 09, 2019 12:00 AM' AS DATETIME USING 'en-US'), 101)
```

to convert it to `mm/dd/yy`.

Comment: One upvote from my side. `TRY_PARSE` is the only approach to specify the culture. But it is very slow...

Comment: Thanks gotqn, I am getting this error   "Error: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An error occurred translating the query string to UTF-16: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page)"  while running at W3school.

Comment: @samy Could you give me the link in W3school where you are executing the code?